# KVM Virtual machine running Windows XP: How to get files from guest to host?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, qemu, kvm

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, and on it, kvm/qemu. I created a storage device with the 'raw' format and installed XP on it, so I assume the file has ntfs format. I have a file on the XP virtual machine that I want on the host. It's 2gigs, so I can't just use a zip drive or burn it to CD.

I tried mounting the file (`winxp.img`) using losetup:

```
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop1 winxp.img
$ sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [0801]:40637460 (/home/robert/kvm/images/winxp.img)
$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/loop1 /home/robert/kvm/images/tmp
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I thought that would work. It didn't. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

winxp.img and loop1 is not a single partition (which can be mounted), it is image of full hard disk with own partition table.

You should read partition table from loop1 with fdisk; compute offset of first partition and do:

```
sudo mount -o offset=N -t ntfs /dev/loop1 /home/robert/kvm/images/tmp
```

where N is offset in bytes.

*Telepathic mode on*
N is 32256
*Telepathic mode off*

and finally, google mode on (I'll google "offset 32256"):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Mounting_an_image_on_the_host

> Linux and other Unix-like hosts can mount images created with the raw format type using a loopback device. From a root login (or using sudo), mount a loopback with an offset of 32,256.
>
> `mount -o loop,offset=32256 /path/to/image.img /mnt/mountpoint`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the generic and correct way is via libguestfs http://libguestfs.org/
If you master it, you can open every virtual image in any format and get files or even make snapshots